# Evaluate $\int \frac{11xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Evaluate $\int \frac{11xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$

Can somebody check my solution? Thanks!!

Let $u=11xe^{2x}$

then $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(11xe^{2x})$
$=11(e^{2x}+2xe^{2x})$

and so $du=11e^{2x}(2x+1)dx$

Now, let $dv=\frac{1}{(2x+1)^2}dx$

Then $\int dv = \int \frac{1}{(2x+1)^2}dx$

To evaluate this, let $r=2x+1$ and so $dr = 2dx$

Then we have $\int dv = \int \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{dr}{2} = \frac{-1}{2r}=\frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}$

So $v=\frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}$

Wow... So that was already a lot of work to find $du$ and $v$ once we chose $u$ and $dv$... Integration by parts totally sucks!!

Anyway, we are now ready to use our VOODOO formula!!

$\int \frac{11xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx = \int udv = uv - \int vdu$

$=(11xe^{2x})(\frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}) - \int \frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}(11e^{2x}(2x+1))dx$

Now, there is a $2x+1$ in the denominator and the numerator so the cancel. We also pull the coefficient $\frac{-11}{2}$ outside of the integral, which we can do.

$=\frac{-11xe^{2x}}{2(2x+1)} + \frac{11}{2}\int e^{2x}dx$

$=\frac{-11xe^{2x}}{2(2x+1)} + \frac{11}{2} \frac{e^{2x}}{2}+C$

$=\frac{-11xe^{2x}}{2(2x+1)} + \frac{11}{4} e^{2x}+C$

Comment: just differentiate your answer to check your solution

Comment: If you use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+%5Cfrac%7B-11xe%5E%7B2x%7D%7D%7B2%282x%2B1%29%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B4%7D+e%5E%7B2x%7D) to differentiate the last line, you are correct. When you integrate $\frac{1}{(2x+1)^2}$, you can apply the anti-chain rule, which says you need to divide by a factor of $2$. Then you can just apply the power rule like with $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ to arrive at the same answer, with much less effort of course.

Comment: the answer would be $\frac{e^{2x}}{4(1+2x)} +C\$ , refer  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h511198p2870398

Comment: @VenkatAmith This question has an extra factor of $11$. Even if you do that, the two answers are equivalent up to a constant.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a short time to compute antiderivatives looking like
$$I=\int \frac {e^{k x}\,P_n(x)} {[Q_m(x)]^r} \,dx$$ think that a *possible* solution could be of the form
$$\frac {e^{k x}\,R_p(x)} {[Q_m(x)]^{r-1}}$$ where $P,Q,R$ are polynomials of different degrees.

Differentiate both sides to get
$$\frac {e^{k x}} {[Q_m(x)]^r}\,P_n(x)=\frac {e^{k x}} {[Q_m(x)]^r}\left(Q_m(x) \left(k R_p(x)+R_p'(x)\right)+(1-r) R_p(x) Q_m'(x) \right)$$ Comparing the degrees, we then have
$$n=m+p+p(m-1)\implies p=\frac n m-1$$ So, in $n$ is a muliple of $m$, big hope !

Tring for your case $n=1$, $m-1$, then $p=0$ that is to say that $R_p(x)$ is just a constant  $R_p(x)=a$. Ralacing all numbers, we then have
$$11x=(2x+1) (2 a+0)+(1-2)a 2=4a x\implies a=\frac {11}4$$

$$\int \frac{11xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx=\frac {11 e^{2x}}{4(1+2x)}$$

As you can notice, I did not use any integration step to get the final result.

Comment: Was thinking in the same line.$(+1)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. In French, we have an expression which is more or less *"Great minds meet"*. The problem  is I am not one. Cheers :-)

Comment: The problem actually solves anomaly :)

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct, but it can be further simplified:

$$\frac{-11xe^{2x}}{2(2x+1)} + \frac{11}{4}e^{2x}$$
$$=\frac{11}{4}e^{2x} \left(\frac{-2x}{2x+1} + 1 \right) =\frac{11}{4}e^{2x} \left(\frac{-2x-1}{2x+1} + \frac{1}{2x+1} + 1 \right)$$
$$=\frac{11}{4}e^{2x} \cdot \frac{1}{2x+1} = \frac{11e^{2x}}{4(2x+1)}$$

which is the same as the answer in Venkat Amith's comment.